# To remove blank space for first field

Tags: unix, awk, split

I want to remove space after excluded first 3 columns,

can anyone help me?

this is my command:

awk -F"|" '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}'HIRE_PURCHASE_testing.csv > farahjihan.csv

My output be like:

```
xxxName      Car       Account Number
xxxFara      Proton    XXXXXXXXXXXXX
xxxJiha      Saga      XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My desired output:

```
Name      Car       Account Number
Fara      Proton    XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Jiha      Saga      XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The *my output be like* having spacing after remove the column

small x is blank space

Comment: please share your input file.

Comment: From your actual vs desired output, it seems that what you want to do is delete leading spaces (i.e.spaces at the beginning of each line before the first "actual" column.) Is that correct?

Comment: ya @Nick how to remove it?

Comment: I would do it with sed, rather than awk: `sed 's/^ *//' input.file > output.file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command to remove the space which appears after removing the space -

```
cat f
ew|ew|ew|Name|Car|Account Number
ew|ew|dw|Fara|Proton|XXXXXXXXXXXXX
ew|ew|dw|Jiha|Saga|XXXXXXXXXXXXX


awk -F"|" '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' f
   Name Car Account Number
   Fara Proton XXXXXXXXXXXXX
   Jiha Saga XXXXXXXXXXXXX


awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=x && i!=y && i!=z)f=f?f OFS $i:$i;print f;f=""}'   x=1 y=2 z=3 f
Name Car Account Number
Fara Proton XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Jiha Saga XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I cannot run it come out with num 1 parsed is not correctt..actually the **x**, small x is blank space..

Comment: I want to remove blank space infront of name field, the small x is blank space @VIPINKUMAR

Comment: @Jiji - try this : awk -F"|" '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' f|sed 's/^ *//g'

Comment: @Jiji - Check my updated answer for awk only solution.

Comment: I tried already..thank u..but can I added above command to my completed command? as this **awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} {file="INITIATION_V1_"$1""$2""date".csv"; print (a[file]++?"": "Detail "date"" ORS h ORS) $0 > file} END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' HIRE_PURCHASE_testing.csv** @VIPINKUMAR

Comment: @Jiji - I will suggest you to create a new thread for this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616655/to-remove-blank-space-for-first-field/42617289#42617289 refer this